# Only show total loss during training of a multi-output model in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I am implementing an autoencoder model via the functional API of Keras. My model is multi-output, with a consequence that a loss function is evaluated on each output. During training, a weighted sum of these losses is minimized:

```py
losses = [jsd for j in range(m)]  # JSD loss function for each output
autoencoder = Model(inputs, decodes)
sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss=losses, loss_weights=[1 for k in range(m)]) # each output has the same priority
```

I then fit my model to training-data and evaluate it on test-data:

```py
history = autoencoder.fit(train_corr, train_attr_corr, epochs=50, batch_size=10, shuffle=True, verbose=2,
                          validation_data=(test_corr, test_attr_GT))
```

As `verbose=2`, the training and validation loss are displayed in the console at the end of each epoch. However, because the model is multi-output, ALL of the 'sub-losses' are displayed. For example:

```
Epoch 1/50
 - 3s - loss: 0.3356 - dense_4_loss: 0.0647 - dense_5_loss: 0.0436 - dense_6_loss: 0.0391 - dense_7_loss: 0.0378 - dense_8_loss: 0.0250 - dense_9_loss: 0.0362 - val_loss: 0.1067 - val_dense_4_loss: 0.0101 - val_dense_5_loss: 0.0042 - val_dense_6_loss: 0.0031 - val_dense_7_loss: 0.0036 - val_dense_8_loss: 0.0041 - val_dense_9_loss: 0.0066
```

**Question**:
Is it possible to only display the total training loss (`loss`) and total validation loss `val_loss` for each epoch?

**Edit**:
In the above example, I only want to display `loss: 0.3356` and `val_loss: 0.1067`.

Comment: Sum of loss for all iterations??

Comment: @abdoulsn No, the sum of all the sub-losses for each epoch. In the above example, I only want to display `loss: 0.3356` and `val_loss: 0.1067`.

Comment: @RutgerMauritz does the answer provided help you with the expected outcome?

Comment: @DrSpill that worked! It's easier than I thought it would be, when using the Callback function. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible using the default verbosity options in the Keras model.fit function. However, you can achieve this using a custom callback. Disable verbosity in the fit function using `verbosity=0`. Define the following callback function that overrides the default callback with modified outcomes on epoch begin and end.

```
class PrinterCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):

    # def on_train_batch_begin(self, batch, logs=None):
    #     # Do something on begin of training batch

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        print('EPOCH: {}, Train Loss: {}, Val Loss: {}'.format(epoch,
                                                               logs['loss'],
                                                               logs['val_loss']))

    def on_epoch_begin(self, epoch, logs=None):
        print('-'*50)
        print('STARTING EPOCH: {}'.format(epoch))

    # def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    #     # Do something on end of training batch
    #
```

While calling model.fit use this callback as `callback=[PrinterCallback()]`. There are other functions that can also be manipulated here. For example, what you can do on train begin, etc. (Couple of examples shown in the code). Feel free to modify how the desired values are printed, for example, controlling the decimal places.

Details on Keras Callback are available [here](https://keras.io/callbacks/) and you can also check the source code for other Callbacks to implement your own.

Hope that helps!